# Android Dumpstate Crash Logs Appearing Randomily

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, crashes

I own a Galaxy Nexus, currently running Android 4.0.4 and ever since I've updated to 4.0.4 I've had problems in that it randomly asks me to share content (without saying what it is) and when I view the files it attaches I see that it includes a dumpstate log and a screenshot.

Is there a way to find what is causing this or stop this from happening?

Samsung support don't give me any help besides the usual battery in-out reboot and restore to factory defaults (which I have both tried already).

Comment: Could you post the log up somewhere?

Comment: The log is about 4MB and contains a lot of information which may be personal or too revealing about what's happening on the phone (e.g. GPS position, email address, etc.). Is there an automated way to reliably anonmyise a dumpstate?

Comment: Not that I know of, you could just search your name/email/dob and replace all with *s? A 4MB log seems huge! :/ You could try looking at the logcat from your phone just after this share content thing pops up, there's an app called Android System Info for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are accidently triggering the generation of a bug reports, as described on this [google support site](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/request.py?&src=6279961&contact_type=android_bugreport) (click on the nexus link):

> Generate a bug report immediately:
>   Press Volume (in between Up and Down) and Power at the same time (after a >significant delay -- up to a minute -- the device will vibrate if successful and open a new message in Gmail).

In my case, my device had a case which was triggering the bug report by inadvertently pressing 'volume' and 'power'

Comment: That sounds like a likely cause, and the delay explains why I hadn't noticed what it was. The button positions on the Galaxy Nexus is just so stupid though...